# sub report header need to show were ever sub report is shooing in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report like this:
[image]

In this crystal report i have 2 sub reports

> 1.Delparkingtype.rpt
>   2.DelivaryDetailedrpt

i want to show DelivaryDetailedrpt headers where ever showing DelivaryDetailedrpt  report
i try to set property repeat on horizontal pages..but that is not affecting any where..
so what i have to do
if any one know how to show subreport header to show where ever sub report showing..please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subreports don't have Page Headers or Footers, but there is a workaround to getting them displayed by creating a "dummy" group. A great tutorial on how to do this can be found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/SubReportPH10062006160749PM/SubReportPH.aspx).

Comment: +1. Group approach works well. btw, subreport does have page header & footer, but they do not repeat themself when subreport across more than 1 page.